# iOS5 : Why does setDelegate:self cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS in main.m?

Tags: ios5

EDIT: I actually traced it to the line where I call [in open]; and try to open the input stream. For some reason, my custom class may be an invalid delegate? I saw somebody else had the same error and did not have the problem after moving everything to a ViewController subclass rather than a custom class extending NSObject. However, I would still like to use my own custom class and not one of the ViewControllers.

I have a Connection class which I coded myself and I use NSInputStream and NSOutputStream. I initialize the streams in the init method:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        messages = [NSMutableArray new];

        CFReadStreamRef readStream;
        CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)HOST, PORT, &readStream, &writeStream);
        [self setIn: (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream];
        [self setOut: (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream];
        NSLog(@"Streams opened.");
        NSLog(@"ConnectionController initialized...");
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, here's the definition for my connection class in the .h

```
@interface ConnectionController : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *messages;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSInputStream *in;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOutputStream *out;

-(void)sendMessage:(NSString*)msg;
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)eStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode;
-(void)messageReceived:(NSString*)msg;
@end
```

When I call this method openStreams, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
- (void)openStreams {
    [in setDelegate:self];
    [out setDelegate:self];

    [in scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [out scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [in open];
    [out open];
}
```

When I comment out setDelegate:self, the error does not occur. However, I need this in order to use the event-driven method for handling NSStreamEvents
How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I am not too familiar with these classes, but the documentation for NSStream (which NSInput/Output streams inherit from) says:  `delegate and setDelegate:
Return and set the delegate. By a default, a stream object must be its own delegate; so a setDelegate: message with an argument of nil should restore this delegate.`

Comment: Is it possible the delegate object got released and deallocated somewhere along the line?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is whatever instance of the Connection class (which is set to be the delegate) is being deallocated (causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the run loop) either because you didn't retain it, or you are using ARC (pretty likely) and you do not have a reference to it.

The solution is to either call retain on the connection class, like so:

```
Connection *connection = [[Connection alloc] init];
[connection retain];
```

Or if you do have ARC enabled, make an instance variable in the class where you alloc Connection, and store your instance of connection there. That way ARC will not dealloc it, because the instance var counts as a reference.